# Add grouping tags in flex structure

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I got the following input structure :

*css*

```
.form-content {
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;

  .form-flex-col-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;

    .form-flex-col-content {
      flex: 1 1 32%;
      padding: 0 10px;
    }
  }
}
```

*html*

```
<div class="form-flex-col-container">
  <div class="form-flex-col-content">
    ... my input
  </div>
  <div class="form-flex-col-content">
    ... my input
  </div>
  <div class="form-flex-col-content">
    ... my input
  </div>
  <div class="form-flex-col-content">
    ... my input
  </div>
  <div class="form-flex-col-content">
    ... my input
  </div>
</div>
```

And it renders well.
However, I would like to introduce a new tag to "group" my `.form-flex-col-content` blocks (in order to provide the angular formControl directive).
Like this :

```
<div class="form-flex-col-container">
<span [formGroup]="myFormA">
  <div class="form-flex-col-content">
    ... my input
  </div>
  <div class="form-flex-col-content">
    ... my input
  </div>
  <div class="form-flex-col-content">
    ... my input
  </div>
</span>
<span [formGroup]="myFormB">
  <div class="form-flex-col-content">
    ... my input
  </div>
  <div class="form-flex-col-content">
    ... my input
  </div>
</span>
</div>
```

But it breaks the flex display.

Is there any tag/style I can use that would not break the flex display ?

Cheers !

Comment: Your `span` is now `form-flex-col-container`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `display: contents` to the `<span>` that wraps the content, to make it effectively transparent to the layout, though this does come with accessibility caveats, unfortunately:

```css
*, ::before, ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font: normal 1rem / 1.5 sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.form-flex-col-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  outline: 2px solid #f90;
}

.form-flex-col-container span {
  display: contents;
}

.form-flex-col-content {
  flex: 1 1 32%;
  padding-block: 10px;
  outline: 2px solid palegreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-flex-col-container">
<span [formGroup]="myFormA">
  <div class="form-flex-col-content">
    ... my input
  </div>
  <div class="form-flex-col-content">
    ... my input
  </div>
  <div class="form-flex-col-content">
    ... my input
  </div>
</span>
<span [formGroup]="myFormB">
  <div class="form-flex-col-content">
    ... my input
  </div>
  <div class="form-flex-col-content">
    ... my input
  </div>
</span>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/qbhx1eo7/1/).

> These elements don't produce a specific box by themselves. They are replaced by their pseudo-box and their child boxes. Please note that the CSS Display Level 3 spec defines how the contents value should affect "unusual elements" — elements that aren’t rendered purely by CSS box concepts such as replaced elements. See [Appendix B: Effects of display: contents on Unusual Elements](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-display/#unbox) for more details.
>
> Due to a bug in browsers, this will currently remove the element from the accessibility tree — screen readers will not look at what's inside. See the [Accessibility concerns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#accessibility_concerns) section below for more details.
> Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#box

References:

- [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).